# Configure multi-line function call indentation in eslint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, formatting, eslint

How do I configure the eslint indent rules for function calls that span multiple lines?

For example, in the following code, with the indent set to 2, eslint complains that the second line of the `expect` call should be indented 8 spaces instead of 6.

1. Why 8?
2. How do I configure this?

--

```
  test('#updateEntries fetches entries', () => {
    c.updateEntries();
    expect(mockDataService.fetchTodaysEntries).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockModel.currentDate,
      expect.any(Function));
  });
```

For what it's worth: The actual problem is that there is a conflict between the built-in VS Code formatter and eslint.  I actually don't care whether the indent is 6 or 8, I just want to get rid of the red squiggly lines without either (1) turning all indention off, (2) having to have an "ignore" comment for each multi-line function call, or (3) having to install a different formatter.  (I'm pretty sure I can't configure this aspect of the built-in VS code formatter; but, correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: You can try the [`@stylistic/eslint-plugin-js`](https://eslint.style/packages/js) plugin, which lets you set the [`indent`](https://eslint.style/rules/js/indent#indent) rule.

Comment: Which indent option applies to this situation? I don't see anything that seems to describe function calls.